# Efficient allocation of slices (cap vs length)

Tags: go, slice

Assuming I am creating a slice, which I know in advance that I want to populate via a for loop with `1e5` elements via successive calls to `append`:

```
// Append 1e5 strings to the slice

for i := 0; i<= 1e5; i++ {
    value := fmt.Sprintf("Entry: %d", i)
    myslice = append(myslice, value)
}
```

which is the more efficient way of initialising the slice and why:

a. declaring a nil slice of strings?

```
var myslice []string
```

b. setting its length in advance to `1e5`?

```
myslice = make([]string, 1e5)
```

c. setting both its length and capacity to `1e5`?

```
myslice = make([]string, 1e5, 1e5)
```

Comment: capacity is equal length by default, so you don't need to set them both to the same value. If you're specifying capacity, normally it's larger than length. Else you can simply omit it.

Comment: Option b and c does _not_ work with `append`. If you know the length in advance then clearly you should make a slice of appropriate capacity, e.g. `make([]string, 0, 1e5)`. Whether you make a slice with the final length and assign to its elements or make a zero-length slice with large capacity and append is a matter of A) taste, B) the code and C) the result of your benchmarks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your `b` and `c` solutions are identical: creating a slice with [`make()`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#make) where you don't specify the capacity, the "missing" capacity defaults to the given length.

Also note that if you create the slice with a length in advance, you can't use [`append()`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#append) to populate the slice, because it adds **new** elements to the slice, and it doesn't "reuse" the allocated elements. So in that case you have to assign values to the elements using an [index expression](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Index_expressions), e.g. `myslice[i] = value`.

If you start with a slice with 0 capacity, a new backing array have to be allocated and "old" content have to be copied over whenever you append an element that does not fit into the capacity, so that solution must be slower inherently.

I would define and consider the following different solutions (I use an `[]int` slice to avoid `fmt.Sprintf()` to intervene / interfere with our benchmarks):

```
var s []int

func BenchmarkA(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        s = nil
        for j := 0; j < 1e5; j++ {
            s = append(s, j)
        }
    }
}

func BenchmarkB(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        s = make([]int, 0, 1e5)
        for j := 0; j < 1e5; j++ {
            s = append(s, j)
        }
    }
}

func BenchmarkBLocal(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        s := make([]int, 0, 1e5)
        for j := 0; j < 1e5; j++ {
            s = append(s, j)
        }
    }
}

func BenchmarkD(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        s = make([]int, 1e5)
        for j := range s {
            s[j] = j
        }
    }
}
```

*Note: I use package level variables in benchmarks (except `BLocal`), because some optimization may (and actually do) happen when using a local slice variable).*

And the benchmark results:

```
BenchmarkA-4         1000     1081599 ns/op     4654332 B/op     30 allocs/op
BenchmarkB-4         3000      371096 ns/op      802816 B/op      1 allocs/op
BenchmarkBLocal-4   10000      172427 ns/op      802816 B/op      1 allocs/op
BenchmarkD-4        10000      167305 ns/op      802816 B/op      1 allocs/op
```

`A`: As you can see, starting with a `nil` slice is the slowest, uses the most memory and allocations.

`B`: Pre-allocating the slice with capacity (but still 0 length) and using append: it requires only a **single allocation** and is much faster, almost **thrice as fast**.

`BLocal`: Do note that when using a local slice instead of a package variable, (compiler) optimizations happen and it gets a lot faster: **twice as fast, almost as fast as `D`**.

`D`: Not using `append()` but assigning elements to a preallocated slice wins in every aspect, even when using a non-local variable.

Answer (score 0):

For this use case, since you already know the number of string elements that you want to assign to the slice,

I would prefer approach **b or c**.

Since you will prevent resizing of the slice using these two approaches.

If you choose to use approach **a**, the slice will double its size everytime a new element is added after len equals capacity.

https://play.golang.org/p/kSuX7cE176j